# Insert oneToMany by cascade causing an error when adding multiple children, NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate

Project is using Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.1 Final
It works fine if adding just one child object.  It raised an error with 2 or more.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

```
//parent

@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBER")
public class Member implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private int memberId;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roleList;

    //getters setters
    //...
    //...
}
```

```
//child
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBER_ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private int roleId;

    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private Member member;

    //getters setters
    //...
    //...
}
```

```
//DAO
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void saveOrUpdate(Member m) {

        Member member = new Member();
        member.setUsername(m.getUsername());
        member.setPassword(m.getPassword());

        /*
         * It works with one object Role
         */
        List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
        roleList.add(new Role("ROLE_USER", member));
        roleList.add(new Role("ROLE_ADMIN", member));

        member.setRoleList(roleList);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(member);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: 
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.project.model.Role#0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't it just because you forgot to tell Hibernate to generate automatically a value for roleId ?

@GeneratedValue is missing here :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
private int roleId;
```